# how do I dynamically toggle a button image using different font-awesome images?

Tags: html, angular

I have a button that should toggle between a font-awesome image for "Run" and "Pause", with every user click that is.

What does the syntax for that look like in an angular application?
The reason I ask for standard approach/suggestion is I have tried with 2 different buttons and using ng-show and have had no luck.

Comment: *When* should it toggle? What is the trigger? When someone clicks on the icon? When someone hovers over it? How many times should the toggle iterate? How quickly? Your question is too broad as it stands. Please add some **context** to help clarify your **intent**. You're also expected to showcase what you have tried so far, clearly stating where the problem is with your own attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `boolean` value in the component and `*ngIf` statement in HTML to show/hide necessary icon (or any other element), which will be based on that `boolean` value. You also need to add `(click)="isPlaying = !isPlaying"` to that icons to trigger the state:

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="!isPlaying" (click)="isPlaying = !isPlaying"></i>
<i class="fa fa-pause-circle" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="isPlaying" (click)="isPlaying = !isPlaying"></i>
```

Component:

```
public isPlaying: boolean = false;
```

If your logic will be so simple as in my example, it's OK too keep the smallest logic in HTML, but if not - better create a trigger method inside your component.